# Is it possible to check if a singly linked list is a palindrome or not at Θ(n) time complexity without using extra memory?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list, palindrome

I just attended an online interview for an internship and the question was to check if a singly linked list is a palindrome or not. I used some memory to store the data of the linked list. I was asked if I can write a code which doesn't use extra memory. I said it might take more than Θ(n) ie Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Conversation went by and it finally came down to the following:
check whether a **singly linked list** is a palindrome or not **in Θ(n) time** all while **not using extra memory** with the condition that the **input data is left undisturbed**.
I told it was not possible but I was told it actually is and that I should look it up over the internet. But of all the algorithms I saw, at least one of these conditions are violated and I personally feel it is not possible too.

By not using extra memory, I mean not using Θ(n) memory. We are free to use Θ(1) memory of course.

So, if anyone can clear this doubt, thanks in advance :D

Comment: Suppose you have a Linked List then you would use a loop and apply GetLastItem() and GetFirstItem() if they are same then it means so far it is Pallindrome , then DeletLast() and DeleteFirstItem() as well . Then repeat process GetFirstItem() and Last until you reach mid of List if all values were same until you reach Mid it is Palindrome therwise not

Comment: @Wasim, that violates at least two constraints.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible on the condition that the list may be *temporarily* tampered with, restoring it to its original state:

1. Scan the list once to count the number of elements.
2. Using that info, scan the list again to find the first element of the second half of the list. If the list has an odd length, this should be the element *after* the middle one.
3. Reverse that second half of the list. This can be done in linear time using an extra lagging and leading node reference. Remember the reference to the last node which now has become the first node of the reversed second half of the list.
4. Perform yet another traversal of the list, but now *in tandem* with a traversal over the reversed second half of the list. Remember whether all comparisons matched (so it is a palindrome)
5. Restore the reversal by repeating step 3.
6. Return the outcome of step 4

This algorithm uses no linear auxiliary space, and performs a fixed number of traversals over the list, giving it a linear time complexity.